# Is there a more simple way of doing rotate_left3 on CodingBat Python?

Tags: python

The instructions are:

Given an array of ints length 3, return an array with the elements "rotated left" so `{1, 2, 3}` yields `{2, 3, 1}`.

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
    return [nums[1], nums[2], nums[0]]
```

I thought you could use slicing to make it work, but I could be wrong.

Comment: FYI the syntax `{1,2,3}` is a set not a list/array. You can't rotate sets since they are unordered collections.

Comment: @IanAuld Yea the question had that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right, this can be done with slicing:

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
    return nums[1:] + nums[:1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I always get a feeling when I code I could do it shorter, but not always know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Hi @GregoryDolan if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkmark. And tell me if further explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am trying the same approach but i am doing return nums[1:]+nums[0]    It gives me error saying cant concatenate ints, Am i not doing the same thing as said in the solution ? please explain thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code is scalable for arrays that could be larger than 3:

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
  new_list = []
  for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    new_list.append(nums[i+1])
  new_list.append(nums[0])
  return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way. You can create a new list a add all elements to it.

```
def rotate_left3(nums): 
    nums1 = []
    nums1.insert(0, nums[1])
    nums1.insert(1, nums[2])
    nums1.insert(2, nums[0])
    return nums1
```

Answer (score 0):

#This works in Jupyter, but CodingBat rejects it.

```
    def rotate_left3(nums):
        nums.append(nums.pop(0))
```

Comment: You need to return the value you compute.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
  temp = nums[2]
  nums[2] = nums[0]
  nums[0] = nums[1]
  nums[1] = temp
  return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Fun way using append operator


 def rotate_left3(nums):
   numlist = []
   numlist.append(nums[1])
   numlist.append(nums[2])
   numlist.append(nums[0])
   return numlist
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Passed at codingbat:

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
    n_n = []
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        n_n.append(nums[i])
    n_n.append(nums[0])
    return n_n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# this works for me on codingbat:

def rotate_left3(nums):
  end = nums.pop(0)
  nums.append(end)
  return nums
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**